# Cycles GPU Compute won't render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

I tried to enable gpu compute with opencl and it says "Loading render kernels this may take a few minutes the first time" when i click render and it just says that forever and never even renders and i have waited for an hour and the render still wouldnt start. there a way to fix it?

Comment: what graphics card do you have? there are some amd cards (like mine) that simply dont work with cycles.

Comment: I have AMD Radeon Peero 460 + Inter HD Graphics 530 on the new Macbook Pro 2016 and I also get this. I would really love to be able to render with the GPU on this machine. It was the same on my old 2012 MBPr and I really hope the blender team can fix this.

Comment: your gpu might not be compatible with cycles

Comment: AMD...Cycles... Bad combo... the dirvers for AMD cards have a long history of problems with cycles...  Unlikely to be fixed soon  Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=amd+cycles+gpu and http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=radeon+cycles+gpu Alternatively **you might want to try other render engines**: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/alternative-render-engines-can-i-use-instead-of-cycles-for-amd-radeon-gpus