# Is my AMD Radeon R5 m335 able to render in Blender? Is this a GPU?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, gpu

Im using Blender **2.78c** and where I have seen in many tutorials people can select their graphics card in the User Preferences>System by clicking CUDA. I only have the option to click OpenCL and when I do it says only Hanain under it.
 [image]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. What system specs, what operating what graphics card, under what OS? With which driver version? Are they up to date?

Comment: I am using A dell (windows) computer blender 2.78 and my graphics card i

Comment: how do i see my kind of graphics card?

Comment: Try the device manager from the control panel and see if it is listed there.

Comment: If you see OpenCL it means you have AMD graphics card, those don't support CUDA for working, it's kind of their analogue. So you likely won't have CUDA but if the card is more or less new likely you won't need CUDA. [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) is often used for card detection.

Comment: I believe my graphics chipset is AMD Radeon R5 M335

Comment: Mr Zak so how do i set uo my AMD graphics card? is it still posible?

Comment: Cegaton no i just found a tutrial of this on youtube and it did not work... It was those steps exactly

Comment: when i open it, it only gives me a Hanain option

Comment: And what happens if you choose Hanain option, enable Experimental features, choose Use GPU compute and try to render?

Comment: Mr Zak i dont know i will try

Comment: i did find out that my graphics card is not supoorted though

Comment: It rendered faster than it was rendering... i gues i will use this method then

Answer (score 1):

[CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is used on Nvidia Cards. AMD Radeon cards use a different kind of hardware.

You can only use Open CL (and live with its [limitations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html)).

The Option "Hainan" is the correct and only option you have.

AMD cards appear in blender with the [code name](http://wccftech.com/amd-radeon-hd-8000-sea-islands-solar-system-codenames/) used for the GPUs architecture.

As an alternative you might want to try using other render engines other than Cycles, as explained in this post: 
[Alternative Render engines can I use instead of Cycles for AMD Radeon GPUs?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/alternative-render-engines-can-i-use-instead-of-cycles-for-amd-radeon-gpus/75403#75403)