# RX580 not supported in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have a Windows PC with RX580. Just installed 2.8 yesterday. Eeviee seems to be working perfectly, while Cycles can render only on CPU. In the Preferences the CUDA tab says that no supported GPUs are found. What do I do?

Comment: Check in the OpenCL tab.

Comment: @rjg I think you should have posted that as an answer. I think that's all there is to it with this question.

Comment: @MartinZ probably. Now you get the sweet reputation points for yourself. I don't think that hurts anybody.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://www.amd.com/de/technologies/radeon-prorender-blender I just found it due to having the same problem with my RX580; just trying it out. Regards,
Roger

Answer (score 3):

You need to select OpenCL instead of CUDA for rendering with AMD cards.

Comment: Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80879/60759 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31795/compute-device-list-not-showing-card-name-when-using-opencl

Comment: How do I switch to OpenCL for Cycles in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 2):

If you have AMD, you specify in the settings as here [image: screenshot]. But unfortunately, Cycles does not work with AMD cards. Only Eevee.

**Sazerac** This proves that Cycles doesn't actually use AMD GPUs when rendering
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Cycles does work, using OpenCL, thats why your screenshot shows the card listed there under 'Cycles Render Devices'. that said AMD card rendering is overall less well developed and tested to likely to have more issues.

Answer (score -1):

> CUDA® is a parallel computing platform and programming model developed
>   by NVIDIA for general computing on graphical processing units (GPUs)

Basically CUDA is NVIDIA's proprietary technology.

Comment: That is true, but the question was "What do I do?", not what CUDA is.